# How can I start a process with admin privileges and in high-priority/real-time from a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, real-time, administrator

I need one batch to open a `.exe file` with admin privileges and in high priority/realtime,without asking for an admin password.

Also, I need to call this batch file from a desktop shortcut.

I have tried:

```
start "%app_name%" /high "%app_name%.exe"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably something like `runas /savecred /profile /env /user:admin "cmd /c start app_name.exe /HIGH"`

Comment: Make the shortcut run `%COMSPEC% C:\path\to\your.bat` and check the "run as admin" box in the shortcut properties.

Comment: runas /savecred /profile /env /user:admin "cmd /c start app_name.exe /HIGH" – Still asks for password

Comment: I can't check the boxes in the shortcut properties because I creat it using Inno Setup compiled installer

Answer (score 0):

I made an installer using Inno setup, the installer made an elevated desktop shortcut to a batch file that started the process in high priority.